# Zf2 Using Zend\Db\Sql\Select

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Need help using Zend\Db\Sql\Select.  Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, it outputs nothing and no errors displayed.

```
namespace Album\Model;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter,
    Zend\Db\Sql\Select;

class AlbumTable
{
    public function getAll()
    {
        $select = new Select('album'); 
        return $select->from();
    }
}

namespace Album\Controller;

class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new Viewmodel(array(
            'rows' => $this->albumTable->useSelect()
        ));
    }
}

// index.phtml
foreach ($this->rows as $row) { echo $row->artist . '<br />'; }
```

Thanks

Comment: You might want to turn on error reporting and display errors in your php configuration to help with resolving errors. For one you are calling an AlbumTable method from your controller which does not exist. It seems you have no Db adapter setup either. I highly recomend running through the getting started guide where all this is explained in great detail.

Comment: Where is this method $this->albumTable->useSelect() coming from?

Comment: Thanks Stoyan & Aydin. I got it working now

Answer (score 1):

Figured I didn't query the string I built.

```
Zend\Db\Sql\Sql; 

class AlbumTable
{
    public function getAll()
    {
        $sql = new Sql($this->adapter);
        $select = new Select('album');

        $selectString = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select);
        return $this->adapter->query($selectString, Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
    }
}
```